# i386-mingw32-g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: g++, mingw

If I compile this QT c++ program in SuSE Linux

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main () 
{ 
cout << "Hello World!"; 
return 0; 
}
```

When I type

> i386-mingw32-g++ helloworld.cpp

I get the following error

> i386-mingw32-g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Is this because MinGW package which i installed contains only gcc in it.. hence i downloaded gcc-g++-3.4.5.rpm package and just copy pasted i386-mingw32-g++ and cc1plus executable along with C++ include files.

Pls reply.
Thanking You

Answer (score 3):

Ugh. The `cc1plus` in gcc-g++-3.4.5.rpm is not for mingw32. You need the one for your distro.

e.g. for Fedora 10, use http://sourceforge.net/projects/outmodedbonsai/files/Mingw%20Cross-compiler/mingw-1.10-1.fc10.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Thanks for the reply...

If it is possible can u pls send me the link for SuSE Linux Distro of mingw-g++.

Pls do reply

Comment: sorry, I can't find any rpm for suse with c++. You may try the "compile from source" way in http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [**here**](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/820984-g-error-trying-exec-cc1plus-execvp-no-such-file-directory):

> It means that your shell could find
>   the g++ frontend of the GNU compiler
>   but that frontend couldn't find
>   cc1plus, the actual C++ compiler; it
>   could find cpp, the preprocessor, it
>   already ran. Go to the directory where
>   the g++ frontend is stored (type:
>   "which g++") and look for the file
>   cc1plus in that same directory or a
>   sub- directory thereof. If it isn't
>   there your compiler installation is
>   broken; if it is there some
>   configuration of it went berzerk.

---

Also, have a look at **[this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-345201.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

suse cross-compile toolchain is here.
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/CrossToolchain:/mingw/